# Postgres: Non zero exit code when executing a sql file?

Tags: database, sql, postgresql, psql

I am writing a shell script which makes calls to psql using 2 forms... one is by command (-c), the other is by file (-f).

e.g. 
psql -c "create table foo (bar integer)"

psql -f foobar.sql

One difference between these forms is that a call by command (-c) returns a non-zero exit code if an error is encountered, while a call by file (-f) always seems to return zero.

I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this behaviour? (i.e. return non-zero if an error occurs while executing a file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out how to resolve this.

I need to enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` at the top of the file.

Example:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP true
```

Comment: +1 for the best solution because it allows me to set the variable *in* the script, so I can trust it always runs correctly and don't have to worry about runtime context.

Answer (score 45):

You can use below statement.

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f foobar.sql
```

This will return the correct return code even `foobar.sql` file doesn't enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` at the top of the file.

Comment: good lord this has come in handy